# Computability of a relation connected to the discrete logarithm

Tags: nt.number-theory, computability-theory

Informally speaking, I was wondering whether the relation

> $a^k \equiv b \text{ (mod } n)$ for some $k,n$

is computable. More formally: Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of the positive integers and set $$R = \big\{(a,b)\in \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}:(\exists k,n \in\mathbb{N}): (n>\max\{a,b\})\land (a^k \equiv b \text{ (mod } n))\big\}.$$ Is $R$ computable?

Comment: What about $k=b$, $n=a^b-b$?

Comment: You are right - see also the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course since $R = \{ (a,b) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \ | \ (a=1) \implies (b=1) \} $.
Indeed for $a > 1$ one can take $n = a^k-b$ for $k$ large enough.

Comment: Note that taking some prime factor of $n$ we may even assume that $n$ is prime.

Comment: @Wojowu:That is much less obvious to achieve because of the condition $n > a,b$.

Comment: ah, right, I've missed that. It should still be true that $n$ may be taken prime, but a separate argument for that would be necessary.